# How to disable parallax on mobile and tablet views?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I know this has been answered before but I would like for someone to show me how to disable my specific code on mobile and tablet view. 
Every time I use a parallax and then view my site on my mobile or tablet, it zooms the image far into where it is not recognizable at all. How can I avoid this?
Thank you.

```css
.parallax {
   height: 800px;
   width: 100%;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax" style="background-image: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.ohi/15678_vegancooking_2o.jpg');">
   <p class="photog" style="color:#FFF;">name here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
@media only screen and (max-width:749px) {
  .parallax {
    background-attachment: inherit;
  }
}
```

just reset the background-attachment on mobile.

Comment: Works like a charm ! You saved my day !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media only screen and (max-width:749px) {
  .parallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
   }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcv7s1b7/2/)..

Comment: this did not work, the image is still very zoomed in on mobile view.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i mean background-size.. look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcv7s1b7/2/)..

Comment: okay that worked, but the image is smooshed... it shows it completely but it looks kind of weird. any fix for that or no?

Comment: @johnstont05 how about using javascript? when the window is resize to small screen the small image renders..